# Smooth special fiber implies smooth generic fiber when proper and flat

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, algebraic-curves

Let $f : X \rightarrow S$ be a morphism between schemes, with $f$ locally of finite presentation, proper and flat, and $S$ the spectrum of a discrete valuation ring with closed point $s$.

Assume that the special fiber $X_s$ is smooth. Is the generic fiber smooth?

In other words: is it impossible to have a flat (algebraic) family of proper singular varieties degenerating into a smooth variety?

Some questions with similar flavour:
[If the reduction is smooth and projective, can I conclude the same about the scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153362/if-the-reduction-is-smooth-and-projective-can-i-conclude-the-same-about-the-sch?rq=1)
[How to understand a fibre over a generic point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497479/how-to-understand-a-fibre-over-a-generic-point?rq=1)
[When is the canonical model of a curve nonsingular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81134/when-is-the-canonical-model-of-a-curve-nonsingular)
[Smoothness of the total space of a family of curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543411/smoothness-of-the-total-space-of-a-family-of-curves)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Here is an argument provided by Kay Rülling, I hope that this is helpful for someone else:

It [is sufficient](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VB) ([and necessary](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V8) because $S$ has just two points: the special point $s$ and the generic point) to show that $f$ is smooth. By [this lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V9) (or [EGA IV, 4](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1967__32__5_0/), 17.5.1), we use local finite presentation and smoothness of the special fiber to conclude that $f$ is smooth on an open $U \subset X$ containing the special fiber $f^{-1}(s)$.

Since $f$ is proper, we conclude that $U = X$, so in particular the generic fiber is smooth. Indeed, $X \setminus U$ is closed; if it were non empty, then the properness of $f$ implies that $f(X \setminus U) \subset S$ is closed and non-empty, and since $S$ is a discrete valuation ring, $f(X \setminus U)$ has to be equal to $s$ or $S$. In both cases $s \in f(X \setminus U)$, which implies that $X \setminus U$ meets $f^{-1}(s)$, hence a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for commenting on an old question. Just to make sure: it looks like the hypothesis that $f$ is flat over $S$ has not been used in your proof, although it follows then from smoothness. The only part where flatness appears is in the "and necessary" argument ; but this is not part of the main proof. Am I correct ?